# Is there a general file content type when using FileEntity

Tags: java, android, httpclient

To use FileEntity, is there a general file conent type which I can set?

Answer (score -1):

you can use application/octet-stream mime type as it is a basic type for binary data i believe.. also, i don't think you should specify mime type for FileEntity as it does this automatically i guess

Comment: FileEntity requires you to supply the mime type.